# How to change --header 'Accept: application/json' to --header 'Accept: application/xml'

Tags: api, server, wso2, response, centos7

WSO2 API manger how to change --header 'Accept: application/json' to --header 'Accept: application/xml'?

I have added some APIs to WSO2 API Publisher. I can connect via API Console for some API but some failed. I noticed the one failing due to --header Accept: application/json'- all other which connected successfully has --header 'Accept: application/xml.

Also it keep return Response Code 0 with Response Headers:

> "error": "no response from server"

I have tried to update this but still the same: /opt/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/sequences/_auth_failure_handler_.xml

Please advise.

Comment: I have test the API using Postman all okay as postman automatically use  --header 'Accept: application/xml'

Answer (score 0):

In the publisher where you define the resources for your API, you can specify the "Produces" field (set it to application/xml), that should be used as the default value from the API Store test console.

Regardless that - the client could post any Accept header in the request. The "Produces" field is only an indication, it doesn't enforce the header value.

I suggest you test the calls anyway using the curl (SoapUI, Postman or any other feasible tool) so you can see what the service REALLY returns. The "Response Code 0" message usually means some error response (400, 500, .. anything) it's just not necessarily shown in the DEV console.

Have fun

Comment: Thank you for you advice, I have tried Produces: text/html this time it changed curl -X GET --header 'Accept: text/xml' the same as good one now. BUT working ok has Request Headers: "Accept": "application/json" while the NOT working has Request Headers:  "Accept": "text/xml" Unfortunately, still return Response Code 0. While I tested in Postman all okay return good result with status 200. Some the applications on the same servers which are working okay on WSO2 API manager using Parameter Type "path" and the Error one is using Parameter Type "header".

Comment: Ok, so the answer helped you to change the Accept header for the DEV console.  "Response code 0" means that the client (your browser) is unable to process response for whatever reason (timeout, not trusted certificate, etc). You could check the browser's dev console (usually F12) what the browser gets. The header is just passed by, don't you overwrite something?